# Yet another "The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called" question

Tags: upgrade, webapi

I am on Sitecore 9.1.

I have read [this question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/sitecore-8-2-with-web-api-2) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969228/ensure-that-httpconfiguration-ensureinitialized); my configuration is as follows.

In order to execute my code on startup, I hijack the **initialize** pipeline:

```
<pipelines>
  <initialize>
    <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers, Sitecore.Kernel']"
      type="MyProject.Pipelines.RegisterHttpRoutes.WebApiConfig, BlueRubicon.Pipelines" />
  </initialize>
</pipelines>
```

My Global.asax is the default one:

```
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application" %>
```

And I have no Global.asax.cs.

This is the **WebApiConfig** class:

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Register);
    }

    public void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("FileUploadApi", "api/FileUpload/{id}",
            new { controller = "FileUpload", id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("CareersApi", "api/careersapi/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "CareersApi", id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Inspiration", "api/inspiration/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Inspiration", id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Brand", "api/Brand/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Brand", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

**Question**

Why am I still getting the *The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code.* error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to register API routes? Its way easier than that.

### code

```
public class InitializeRoutes
{
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        // Registration
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("create-member",
            Constants.BaseRoute
            + Constants.ApiVersion
            + "/membership",
            new { controller = "RegistrationApi", action = "Create" },
            new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
        );
    }
}
```

### config

```
<pipelines>
  <initialize>
    <processor type="YourApp.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeRoutes, YourApp" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
  </initialize>
</pipelines>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks.